# Cant start instance in GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am new to GCE. I signed up for GCE. I setup billing. In the Web UI for GCE I clicked the "New Instance" button. I filled in the form with the settings I wanted for my new instance. Then a window pops up that tells me the instance is being created. It also tells me not to refresh the page or browse away from the page.

I have tried three times and it just sits there spinning. After an hour or two for the first and second try I refreshed the page. I let the third try sit over night with no luck. I see where it made the PD for each of the instances, but the instance we never created. I tried different zones too, with no luck.

Do y'all have any pro tips?

Comment: I'd suggest sending your problem report to gc-team@google.com along with your project id so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 2):

I've observed the same behaviour, I assume GCE console is still not that stable ATM.
After 3 attempts I've turned to [`gcutil`](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/) and it worked perfectly.
You can build your CLI commands by filling forms in WebUI (without confirming actions) and then clicking "Command Line" link on the right.

Note, your previous attempts probably left you with stale disk images, remember to remove them before proceeding.